# How to have multiple providers for one account?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

#### Introduce the problem

I use an email to log in.

If I log out and try to log in to the same email using Google, the UID of the account changes. I can't change back to the old UID. How can I provide multiple providers for an account?

#### What I tried

I asked this question to ChatGPT but it didn't answer my question. I also googled this problem.

I have read [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/account-linking) and used its code, but it didn't work. Not sure if I'm using its code correctly.

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55716180/16124033) but it didn't help me.

#### A minimal, reproducible example

```dart
Future<void> signInWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
  try {
    await firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    final credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(email: email, password: password);
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.linkWithCredential(credential);
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    throw FirebaseAuthException(code: e.code, message: e.message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't call `linkWithCredential` anywhere, which the documentation that you linked shows as the way to link credentials from multiple providers to a single account.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I don't know how to combine the code with mine

Comment: "I have read this documentation and used its code, but it didn't work. Not sure if I'm using its code correctly." What did you try? Can you show the [minimal code that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) after trying to apply what that documentation shows to your app? --- If you haven't tried anything yet, there's probably some good examples in here too: https://www.google.com/search?q=flutter+linkWithCredential

Comment: The code looks fine, so that's probably not it. "but it didn't work" is really hard to help with though. If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?
 Does it even execute the `linkWithCredential` call? Or is `currentUser` null?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen `currentUser` is null

Comment: Yeah, so that explains why you can't link a user. You first need to sign in to the existing provider, so that `currentUser` isn't null, then create credentials for the additional provider, and then finally link the additional provider to the existing account by calling `linkWithCredential`.

Comment: Are you talking about [this code](https://pastebin.com/rq0nLUFb)?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this via the Firebase Console. The Firebase Authentication Settings tab allows you to link accounts with the same email.

https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/yourprojectname/authentication/settings

Comment: Hi, I have allowed it, but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Account linking works by first having a currently signed in user, and then linking an additional provider to it. In steps:

1. Sign in with the existing provider.
2. Check that `currentUser` isn't null.
3. Create credentials for the additional provider
4. Link the additional provider to the existing account by calling `linkWithCredential`.

Comment: I'm not sure if my code is correct. Here is my code: https://pastebin.com/rq0nLUFb

Comment: Please ensure that the [minimal code with whcih anyone can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is in the question itself. Links rot.